# How to delete an element in python list, in O(1) time

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I would like to know if we can delete element at any index, say the last index in O(1) time.

Comment: The last index? Easy. Arbitrary indexes? No.

Comment: All your responses are O(n)

Comment: I don't think you can do that so easily. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity , clearly states average of o(n)

Comment: If you are allowed to rearrange list items, just move the last item to the desired index then delete the last item. That last deletion is O(1). Will that do? If the order must stay the same, you should use another data structure rather than a list.

Comment: To delete the last index in O(1) time, just use `.pop()`.  However, you _cannot_ delete the first index in O(1) time.

Comment: A list is not the correct data structure if O(1) removal at an arbitrary index is a requirement.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, rearranging again would be O(N) anyway, defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: @ishaan That isn't his idea. Just *swap* the two elements, and then delete the last one. Clearly O(1).

Comment: @jonrsharpe : Yeah. .pop() is O(1). deleting any other element at any other index is O(n), if we would want to maintain same ordering

Comment: Thanks all. As john was mentioning, I wanted to swap and delete the element at last index, to enforce deletion as O(1). Thank you John.

Comment: Perhaps *Rory Daulton* or *John Coleman* could write that up as an answer for OP to accept?  If so, I'll delete my addition.

Comment: For some purposes, you could just assign `None` to an element in O(1) time which is a way of marking it as deleted. This won't free up the memory and will make the actual data in your list fragmented and hence slower to iterate over, but if you have a series of deletions to make you could mark various locations for deletion and then build up a new list in a single pass.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, you don't have to swap; just copy the end element to the desired deletion position -- don't bother with the converse assignment -- and pop the last (now redundant) element.  For removing element **n**,

```
my_list[n] = my_list.pop()
```

will do it in one line.

Comment: I checked and found out that this gives error if we are at last element.
`eg. my_list = [1,2,3] and if we do my_list[2] = my_list.pop()`
will give "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"
since pop will reduce list length by 1. 
So need to handle this case when n == len(my_list)-1
just pop().